# What is the inverse of a general sibling combinator?

Tags: css

I'm working on a Wordpress theme where I'd like to add some margin to the nav bar when the WP admin bar is present. The problem is, my navbar is at the top of body and the WP generated admin bar is at the bottom of body. So the following CSS rule doesn't work:

```
.navbar-fixed-top ~ #wpadminbar { margin-top: 30px; }
```

In this case, #wpadminbar gets the margin rather than navbar-fixed-top. I'm using the ~ combinator because I'd only like the margin added when #wpadminbar is present. The reverse doesn't work because the elements are in the wrong order in the HTML

```
#wpadminbar ~ .navbar-fixed-top { margin-top: 30px; }
```

What can I do in this case? Is there a combinator that would be the inverse of ~?

Comment: Think you'll need to go javascript route here. Here's a quick fix with jQuery: `if ($('#wpadminbar').length > 0) { $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('margin-top','30px'); };`

Comment: That'll do it - thanks! My hack was to test for displaying the bar in PHP and add a new class with the margin if it was true.